# Using Model to validata data based on hours in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am new to cakephp.Below the number being bold is the time the data is being created and code to validate .My problem is to validate the data should between 8 hours not more that using  Model. is there any wrong in my code?

sample data=L02A-180129-**1215**-A

The code to find the table based on data

```
public function sa01() {        
$trv_no = $this->data[$this->alias]['TRV_No_01'];       
$line_no = intval(substr($trv_no, 1, 2));       
$table_name = 'Ticket_L' . $line_no;        
$this->Ticket->setSource($table_name);      
$this->Ticket->recursive =-1;
```

code for validation

`Batch_time` is a column name for the table

```
$time = $this->Ticket->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Ticket.Batch_Time >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-8 hour')))));
    if(empty($time))
        {
            $table_name = 'Ticket_L0';
            $this->Ticket->setSource($table_name);
            //$ticket = $this->Ticket->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Ticket.TRV_No' => $trv_no)));
     $time = $this->Ticket->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Ticket.Batch_Time >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-8 hour')))));
            if(empty($time)) { return false; } else { return true; }
         }
         else
        { return true; }
    }
```

Comment: sure it is cake 3?

Comment: no its cakephp 2.6